# check if value is changed between group of transactions

Tags: python, pandas

given this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1],'B':['enters','A','B','C','D','exit','walk','enters','Q','Q','exit'],"Value":[4,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,6]})

    A   B        Value
0   1   enters   4
1   0   A        4
2   0   B        4
3   0   C        4
4   0   D        5
5   1   exit     6
6   0   walk     6
7   1   enters   6
8   0   Q        6
9   0   Q        6
10  1   exit     6
```

There are 2 'transactions' here. When someone enters and leaves. So tx#1 is between 0 and 5 and tx#2 between 7 and 10.

My goal is to show if the value was changed? So in tx1 the value has changed from 4 to 6 and in tx#2 no change. Expected result:

```
index   tx  value_before value_after 
  0      1       4             6
  7      2       6             6
```

I tried to fill the 0 between each tx with 1 and then group but I get all A column as 1. I'm not sure how to define the group by if each tx stands on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a new transaction number on each new 'enter' and pivot:

```
df['tx'] = np.where(df.B.eq('enters'),1,0).cumsum()
df[df.B.isin(['enters','exit'])].pivot('tx','B','Value')
```

Result:

```
B   enters  exit
tx              
1        4     6
2        6     6
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want but it has all the info

```
df[df['B'].isin(['enters', 'exit'])].drop(['A'], axis=1).reset_index()

   index       B  Value
0      0  enters      4
1      5    exit      6
2      7  enters      6
3     10    exit      6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you need with `cumsum()`, and `pivot_table()`:

```
df['tx'] = np.where(df['B']=='enters',1,0).cumsum()

res = pd.pivot_table(df[df['B'].isin(['enters','exit'])],
                     index=['tx'],columns=['B'],values='Value'
                     ).reset_index().rename(columns ={'enters':'value_before','exit':'value_after'})
```

Which prints:

```
res

   tx  value_before  value_after
0  1             4            6
1  2             6            6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have a sequence "enters - exit" you can create a new dataframe and assign certain values to each column:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'tx': [x + 1 for x in range(len(new_df['value_before']))],
                       'value_before': df['Value'].loc[df['B'] == 'enters'],
                       'value_after': list(df['Value'].loc[df['B'] == 'exit'])})
```

Output:

```
   tx   value_before    value_after
0   1              4              6
7   2              6              6
```

You can add 'reset_index(drop=True)' at the end if you don't want to see an index from the original dataframe.

I added 'list' for 'value_after' to get right concatenation.